# Error is being thrown claiming that a method created in an axios class is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, es6-class

In my react application, I'm defining an Axios class with a bunch of methods, but the methods are not being recognized as functions and throwing an error. Showing is easier than explaining so... I have 3 files involved...

http-common.js has this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/api/v1/tours",
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json"
    }
});
```

tours.js has this:

```
import http from "../http-common";

class ToursDataService {

    getAll(page = 0) {
        return http.get(`?page=${page}`);
    }

}

export default ToursDataService
```

tours-list.js has this... which calls the function "getAll" in retrieveTours.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ToursDataService from "../services/tours";

const ToursList = props => {
    const [tours, setTours] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        retrieveTours();
    }, []);

const retrieveTours = () => {
    ToursDataService.getAll()
        .then(response => {
            setTours(response.data.tours)
        })
        .catch( e => {
            console.log(e);
        });
}
```

The console claims that getAll is not a function. Why? Can anyone explain?

```
scheduler.development.js:173 Uncaught TypeError: _services_tours__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.getAll is not a function
    at retrieveTours (tour-list.js:12:1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`getAll()` is not a static method so you'd need to create an instance of `ToursDataService`...

```js
const svc = new ToursDataService(); // create an instance

// ...

svc.getAll() // call the method on the instance
  .then(...)
```

or make the method [static](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)

```js
class ToursDataService {
  static getAll(page = 0) {
    return http.get("", { params: { page } });
  }
}
```

---

Alternately, don't use classes at all since you don't appear to be encapsulating anything. You might as well just export the `getAll` function on its own

```js
// tours.js
export const getAll = (page = 0) => http.get("", { params: { page } });
```

and

```js
import { getAll } from "../services/tours";
```

Comment: Ah ok. I see it now. I'll probably go with that final idea. Thanks!

Comment: @anthonygalligani you're welcome. You could even use something like `import * as ToursDataService from "../services/tours"` which is pretty much the same as a class with static methods

Comment: That's pobably even better.